# (Python 3.7 |Discord.py) mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py, mysql-connector

I have a dpy bot and I use ysql.connector to connect to my database.
At that part of my code:

```py
# Dep money to a user's bank
@commands.command(aliases=["dep"])
async def deposit(ctx, _amount):
    userid = ctx.author.id
    try:
        connection = udb.connection
        cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM economy WHERE UserID = {userid}"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        values = cursor.fetchone()
        cash = int(values["Cash"])
        bank = int(values["Bank"])
        if values is None:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.display_name} is not initialized, please use `.bal {ctx.author.name}` first.")
            return
        amount = _amount
```

I get that error (with traceback):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/gurvanbk/winter/commands_files/deposit.py", line 76, in deposit
    cursor.fetchall()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 1252, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError(ERR_NO_RESULT_TO_FETCH)

mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from
```

Could someone explain to me why? I looked at some other posts, but people were using twice "cursor.fetchall()", I don't do.

Comment: The error is talking about ```cursor.fetchall()
``` but your code snippet never mentions such a command. Are you sure you are sending the correct code snippet?

Comment: Oh s**t, I didn't see that line in my code, it was wrapped. Thanks. Should I delete my question or self answer? Or you answer?

Comment: I'd say answer yourself, I mean you practically figured the problem out yourself. It will be more useful for people who are getting to this from Google.